# Writing a random-generating quiz, need to recall the object that was randomly generated

Tags: python

I'm very new to python, so I'm sure my code is prodigiously inefficient, etc, but I'm just feeling my way around and learning by doing at the moment, so excuse my general ignorance.

My quiz currently takes a series of quotes and randomly prints the first 20 characters of them (via slice), the idea being that the quizee recites the rest.

I would like to add the ability to fetch the entire quote, but I don't know how to tell python to recall the last object the random module generated.

Here is my code:

```
import random
control = True

JCIIiii34 = "Valiant men never taste of death but once"
SonnetSeventeen = "If I could write the beauty of your eyes,\nAnd in fresh numbers number all your graces,\nThe age to come would say this poet lies,\nSuch heavenly touches ne'er touched earthly faces."
SonnetEighteen = "So long as men can breath and eyes can see,\nSo long lives this, and this gives life to thee."
JCIii101 = "I had as lief not be as live to be\nIn awe of such a thing as I myself"


print "After quote type 'exit' to leave, or 'next' for next quote"

while control:
    quote = random.choice([SonnetSeventeen,SonnetEighteen,JCIIiii,JCIii])
    print quote[:20]
    var = raw_input ("\n")
    if var == "exit":
        control = False
    elif var == "next":
        print "\n"
        control = True
```

So what I'd like to be able to do is add one more elif statement saying

```
elif var == "answer":
     print #the full quote
```

Where the print statement calls to the object that was originally sliced, but prints it in full.

I have read the python library entry for the random module and found no answer.

I'm also open to more efficient ways of doing this (I know I can store the quotes in a separate file, but haven't figured that out yet).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `quote` itself:

```
while control:
    quote = random.choice([SonnetSeventeen,SonnetEighteen,JCIIiii34,JCIii101])
    print quote[:20]
    var = raw_input ("\n")
    if var == "exit":
        control = False
    elif var == "next":
        print "\n"
        control = True
    elif var == "answer":
        print quote
```

Comment: Well I feel like a fool. I considered it, but assumed it would just randomly generate again. So if I'm not mistaken, when in a while loop such as this, the random module will not randomize again until it loops through, and the object "quote" will temporarily point to the last generated object until it loops through again. Is that accurate? edit: Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's it. If you need to keep it for longer, just save the quote in another variable (like `last_quote`).

Answer (score 2):

`quote[:20]` doesn't destroy your original `quote`. So plain `print quote` should work!

(BTW. If you still need it, you do not have to recall the last value from `random`, you can just store the last value it returned)

Comment: I'm a dummy. I assumed that since quote was assigned to a randomly generating object, it would randomly generate every time it was called, but I guess in a loop it will only generates once until it is told to generate again.

Comment: No, you are right - it will regenerate every time. I assumed the user is supposed to answer quiz in one loop cycle. If not, you should move quote choosing method outside of current loop and introduce another loop: innner loop for guessing current quote, outer loop for program logic (next quote/exit)

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Emilio, but you could also use print[20:] to just print the rest of the quote that was not displayed previously. Also, to simpifly what Emilio said, you could just do:

```
  while True:
    quote = random.choice([SonnetSeventeen,SonnetEighteen,JCIIiii34,JCIii101])
    print quote[:20]
    var = raw_input ("\n")
    if var == "exit":
        break
    elif var == "next":
        print "\n"
    elif var == "answer":
        print quote[20:]
```

In the "elif var == 'next' " statement, you don't need to assign control to True since it is already True when it reaches that point.